# springboot could not found feignclient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

ERROR INFO LIKE BELOW:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field helloAgent in com.example.client.controller.Hello required a bean of 
type 'com.example.common.agent.HelloAgent' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.common.agent.HelloAgent' in 
your configuration.
```

### project structure:

module: test-client as feignclient caller.

module: test-server as feignclient interface implementation.

module: test-common put all feignclient together.

### test-common:

```
package com.example.common.agent;
@FeignClient("hello")
public interface HelloAgent {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String hello(@RequestParam String msg);
}
```

### test-server:(works fine)

```
package com.example.server.controller;

@RestController
public class Hello implements HelloAgent {
    @Override
    public String hello(@RequestParam String msg) {
        System.out.println("get " + msg);
        return "Hi " + msg;
    }
}
```

### test-client:

```
package com.example.client.controller;

@RestController
public class Hello {
    @Autowired
    private HelloAgent helloAgent;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("go");
        String ret = helloAgent.hello("client");
        System.out.println("back " + ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
----------------------------
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.common.agent","com.example.client.controller"})
public class TestClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to put all feignclient together so that we can manage them gracefully?

Or there is only way to use them redundancy?

THANKS!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Feign doesn't know about `@ComponentScan`.

Use `@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.example.common.agent","com.example.client.controller"})`

Comment: Do you know if it was resolved in 2.0.0.M+ versions ?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using Configuration

- In case you use Swagger Codegen, you can use a configuration to bootstrap the apis:

```java
@Configuration
public class ParkingPlusFeignClientConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ParkingPlusProperties properties;

  @Bean
  public ServicoPagamentoTicket2Api ticketApi() {
    ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751269/feign-logging-not-working/59651045#59651045
    client.getFeignBuilder().logLevel(properties.getClientLogLevel());
    client.setBasePath(properties.getHost());
    // Generated from swagger: https://demonstracao.parkingplus.com.br/servicos
    return client.buildClient(ServicoPagamentoTicket2Api.class);
  }

}
```