# What the difference between RestTemplate x Feign Client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to build a Spring `Feign Client` to encapsulate the call to an internal API. In this request, I need to make a login in order to get a token and then use it as a Header parameter for my new request. To set the token dynamically, I used the code below.

```
@FeignClient(value = "APIBuscarCep", url = "${url}")
public interface BuscarCepFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "url-complement", produces = "application/json")
    @Headers({"Authorization: {token}"})
    CepResponseDTO getAddressByCep(@Param("token") String token, @NotNull @PathVariable("cep") String cep);
}
```

Unfortunately, besides the login goes right and get token, my request always returns the `403 code`. (I used postman to check if the request should return successfully).

The only solution that works was using `restTemplate` like the code below.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Authorization", token);
ResponseEntity<CepResponseDTO> exchange;

exchange = restTemplate.exchange(String.format("%s%s", endpoint, cep),              
                                 HttpMethod.GET, header, CepResponseDTO.class);
```

#### Question

- Is there any difference between the building of those classes?
- How can I make the request using Feign Client?

#### Specs

Using Spring boot 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use dynamic value in `@Header` annotation. However, you can use `@RequestHeader` annotation in the input param to do this.

```
@FeignClient(value = "APIBuscarCep", url = "${url}")
public interface BuscarCepFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "url-complement", produces = "application/json")
    CepResponseDTO getAddressByCep(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @NotNull @PathVariable("cep") String cep);
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the Feign debug logs ? You will see the full HTTP trace (headers, body, url), and it will be easy to debug as it works from Postman. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751269/feign-logging-not-working to activate logs

Comment: I also suggest setting up the log level for Trace to debug Feign Classes.